# How to allow paste only for URLS in input?

Tags: javascript, input, copy-paste, paste

What I want is to allow paste in an input only for urls that contain http and https, if the paste does not contain http or https then I do not want to paste anything.

Any recommendation please?

Comment: Hello, welcom on SO! What code did you try?

Comment: You need to capture the paste event and access the clipboard. It won't be supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    if(/^http/.test(text)) {
      window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    }   
});
```

Codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-thompson-wtvvo?file=/src/index.js:59-75

Comment: Hello domenikk, thank you very much for responding. I have tried it but it does not work, maybe I am forming something badly together with the input. Please could you show me a complete example set with an iput field? I am not a web programmer, and I am quite clumsy, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks man! It works fine, but in Firefox paste stops working completely, although you already warned me in the first answer. Anyway thank you very much, I will think of something to disable it in Firefox.

Comment: I have the latest version of Firefox (80.0) and it doesn't work. I have tried to vote positive but I do not have sufficient permissions, it tells me the following: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Hello domenikk, you can put examples right here in your answer as a stack snippet instead of externally as a codesandbox, jsfiddle, codepen, or whatever else. That way your example can never disappear and the link to your example can not ever break.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check if the contents of the paste matches what you want, and prevent the paste if it does not match.

You will want to attach an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your URL field(s) and, when the paste event occurs, test the clipboard contents.

You can get the text of the clipboard contents from the [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) by calling clipboardData.[getData("text/plain")](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) on the event object that your event listener is handling, which will look something like
`let data = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");`

To test if this data matches what you want you can use the regular expression `/^https?:\/\/.*$/`

> `^` matches the *start* of the text — the paste data must *begin* with "http"
> `http` match exactly "http"
> `s?` match (optionally) an `s` - so `https?` matches "http" with an optional "s" after it
> `:\/\/` match the colon-slash-slash `://`, but `/` means something in the regex, so you must escape it with a backslash `\`
> `.*$` match anything else, up until the end of the text `$`

If the clipboard data matches that you want to allow the paste; if it *doesn't* match you want to prevent the event's default behavior of pasting by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

So here you get the URL field `document.getElementById('url-field')` (assuming the field has an *id* of `url-field`) and you *attach* the event listener, listening for a `paste` event.

I have made the input field a `type="url"` field, although this would also work with `type="text"` you get some benefits by making it specifically expect a *url*.
A url field would also accept something like `ftp://example.com/path/filename.txt` so you still want your paste-prevention code anyway.

I *also* add a validation pattern `pattern="^https?://.*$"`on the field itself, so that if you *type* (not paste) something without http(s) it's also counted as being invalid.

```js
document.getElementById('url-field')
  .addEventListener('paste', e => {
      let data = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
      let matched = /^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(data);
      //console.log('data:', data);
      //console.log('matched =', matched);
      if (! matched) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      // -or- putting everything inline, without extra variables
      /*
      if (!/^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(
          e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain")))
      {
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      */
  });
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
div.field {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Paste the URL:
     <input type="url" id="url-field" pattern="^https?://.*$">
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Something else:
     <input type="text" id="notTheUrl">
   </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, if you have more than one URL field and you want to put this "paste rule" on all of them, you can use [`querySelectorAll(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in place of [`getElementById(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), then attach paste-handlers to *each* of the fields (using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) (we'll get into event delegation some other time)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=url]')
    .forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener('paste', e => {
        if (!/^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(
            e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain")))
        { 
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
div.field {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Paste the URL
     <input type="url" pattern="^https?://.*$">
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Something else
     <input type="text" id="notTheUrl">
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Another URL
     <input type="url" id="do-not-need-an-id" pattern="^https?://.*$">
   </label>
  </div>
</form>
```